# Stream Html to the browser when Future completes

Tags: scala, playframework, stream, akka, future

I'm trying to stream *Futures* as *Html* (in Play 2.5.2 in Scala) with the idea being that they will render onscreen when the *Futures* complete. So I would stream a *Source* as a *String* like this:

```
   def oneFuture = Action { request =>
     val source1: Source[String, NotUsed] = fromFuture(sc.makeServiceCall("async1"))
     Ok.chunked(source1)
   }
```

where `sc.makeServiceCall` calls:

```
   class ServiceClient @Inject() (ws: WSClient) {

     def makeServiceCall(serviceName: String): Future[String] = {
       ws.url(s"http://localhost:9000/mock/$serviceName").get().map(_.body)
     }

   }
```

which is referencing:

```
   class Mock @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

     def mock(serviceName: String) = Action.async { request =>
       serviceName match {
         case "async1" => respond("asy1", 1.second)
         case "async2" => respond("asy2", 3.second)
       }
     }

     private def respond(data: String, delay: FiniteDuration): Future[Result] = {
       val promise: Promise[Result] = Promise[Result]()
       actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay) { promise.success(Ok(data)) }
       promise.future
     }

   }
```

Which returns `asy1` after 1 second. So with this in mind **how would I render *Html* in the browser if I wanted to stream a template page**, e.g. `views.html.async1.async1Message("a simple string")` - which is:

```
   @(async1Message: String)

   <span style="color: red; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;">@async1Message</span>
```

Comment: What did you try yet? Did you map the result of the service call into the template and then return it? This seems to be more of a frontend question, how you handle the response in javascript, right? How is the endpoint being called?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you insist on *streaming* the result? You could just return the whole page as asynchronously, it's a small template.

That being said, if this is for learning purposes, you should know that `Source.fromFuture` creates an Akka source with a *single element*. You need to split it into chunks yourself. You could do that like this:

```
val chunkSize = 512 // 512 characters of your string
val source = Source.fromFuture(sc.makeServiceCall("async1"))
  .mapConcat(_.grouped(chunkSize))
Ok.chunked(source)
```

Comment: Yes - this is for learning purposes at this stage. I'm getting a `type mismatch; found   : Iterator[String] required: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[?] .mapConcat(_.grouped(chunkSize))`. Assume the `sc.makeServiceCall("async1")` is a _Future[Result]_ and (as I say) I want to return _HTML markup_